# How to get all information from custom ListView with two different bindings?

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm currently working on a **"Tournament Generator"** and in one step I need to associate a trainer to a team. Therefore I used a **WPF ListView** with integrated Comboboxes. Selection Mode is **"Multiple"** Here's a picture :

Well no picture because of no reputation.

**It looks like this:**

It has two columns. The first columns hold different trainer names. The second column holds in each line a combobox with different teams. For each trainer a team can be selected in the combobox.

**And here's the code:**

```
  <ListView x:Name="TrainerListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Trainer}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Trainer" Width="150"/>

                                <GridViewColumn Header="Team" Width="150">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.Teams}" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

As you can see from the code the ListView has the Trainer property as ItemsSource and the ComboBoxes the Teams property.

After clicking  a button, I want to get all the selected values. Here: "David with FC Liverpool", "Bernd with Borussia Dortmund" and "Tim with Bayern Munic". I tried the following:

```
private void StartTournamentButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItems = TrainerListView.SelectedItems;
}
```

But the selectedItems variable only holds the selected trainer objects "David, Bernd and Tim".

Still I couldn't find a way to retrieve the "Teams values" from the ListView, not to mention an association of Trainer and Team. How do I get the values of the selected rows? Best as associated values.

best regards,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Trainer` class you need to have another property say `AssignedTeam` apart from `Name`.

```
public string AssignedTeam { get; set; }
```

And bind `SelectedItem` of combobox with that property:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                          AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.Teams}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding AssignedTeam}"
          Width="120"/>
```

Now, `SelectedItems will give you list of objects of Trainer class` from where on you can access the team assigned property:

```
var selectedItems = TrainerListView.SelectedItems;
string assignedTeam = ((Trainer)selectedItems[0]).AssignedTeam;
```